# Delay in ffmpeg flow loop

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to run this command below to be in an infinite loop and it worked, but when the video ends and starts to replay, it stops for a few seconds. A kind of lag, delay, buffer and I have no idea how to solve it. Could someone out there help me?

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -threads 2 -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -i input -preset veryfast -b:v 2M -c copy -c:v libx264 -pass 1 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 2048k -f flv output
```

Comment: Which ffmpeg version?

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.2.3 - latest version